# Submit telemetry via gateway mode on HTTP & MQTT adaptors

Tags: eclipse-hono, bosch-iot-suite, bosch-iot

I can create things, set up connections and apply the connection policy to the thing so I can submit telemetry from a thing via HTTP and MQTT and receive it on my MQTT server/connection. I've got all this working.

But when I try to switch to using gateway mode via HTTP or MQTT adaptor it no longer works.

I'm not sure how to authorise a thing to act on behalf of another thing.

When I use the HTTP adaptor I get "gateway unknown, disabled or not authorized to act on behalf of device".

Comment: This question may be more suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) as it appears to be a network administration problem rather than programming. With that said I may be wrong.

Comment: Justin, using the gateway mode with Hono's protocol adapters doesn't require any changes or registrations in IoT Things. However, the gateway that should act on behalf of the device needs to be registered as a device itself in IoT Hub (Hono). Have you registered the gateway? You then also need to authorize that gateway to act on behalf of the device by means of setting the device's *via* property to the gateway's device identifier. All of this should be covered in the IoT Hub docs at https://docs.bosch-iot-suite.com/hub/general-concepts/gatewaymode.html

Comment: Thanks Kai. I have registered my gateway and devices but missed the via as a property of the device registration and the page of documentation you pointed me to.  I should be able to figure it out now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Kai Hudalla pointed out the when registering a device you can set the via property to authorise a gateway to act on it's behalf and its documented at https://docs.bosch-iot-suite.com/hub/general-concepts/gatewaymode.html